# Add textarea in Query Parameter of Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am new to swagger. Currently, I am using swagger ui version v2.1.4. My API consists query parameters. Into that one parameter accepts JSON body. I want to show this parameter into textarea. Currently, it showing in the input tag . also, I want to display Parameter content type below that textarea. How I do that please help me?

Answer (score 3):

In the current swagger 2.0 specification, you can *not* use complex values as query parameters.  They can be primitives or arrays of primitive values.  You can find out more from the specification directly:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameter-object

As this has been a commonly requested feature, it will be supported in the next version of the specification, but the feature will *not* be backported to the swagger 2.0 tooling.

Answer (score 2):

add `format` in describing parameters
eg:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: key
    type: string
    in: query
    format: textarea
```

add custom plugin when init `swagger-ui`

```js
       // Custom plugin that adds extra stuff
       const TextAreaPlugin = function() {
           return {
               wrapComponents: {
                   // add text above InfoContainer - same effect as above title
                   JsonSchema_string: (Original, runtime) => (props) => {
                       var React = runtime.React,
                           schema = props.schema || {},
                           errors = props.errors || {},
                           format = schema.format || "",
                           isDisabled = props.disabled;

                        errors = errors.toJS ? errors.toJS() : []

                       function handleOnChange(e) {
                           const inputValue = e.target.value;

                           props.onChange(inputValue)
                       }

                       if (format == "textarea") {
                           return React.createElement("div", null,
                                   React.createElement("textarea", {
                                       title: errors.length ? errors : "",
                                       className: errors.length ? "invalid" : "",
                                       value: props.value,
                                       disabled: isDisabled,
                                       onChange: handleOnChange
                                   })
                           )
                       }

                       return React.createElement(Original, props);
                   },
               }
           }
       };

       // Begin Swagger UI call region
        var ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
            url: "./swagger.json",
            dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
            deepLinking: true,
            presets: [
                SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
                SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
            ],
            plugins: [
                TextAreaPlugin,
                SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
            ],
            layout: "StandaloneLayout"
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects as query parameters are now supported in OpenAPI 3.0. See this Q&A for an example:
[Use object type query param in Swagger documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51277233/113116)