# Swagger/OpenAPI spec for arrays of objects in URL query parameter

Tags: swagger, openapi

Assume I have a URL which takes a path of: `?filter[id]=1&filter[name]=bob&order[][name]=asc&order[][age]=desc`

How would one be able to convert this into swagger documentation, specifically, array of objects and arrays as the query parameter.

Comment: `filter` and `order[]` are objects in OpenAPI terms. Where's the array?

Comment: There are tools out there to generate the swagger doc for your api for almost every language. Use one of those that way you don't have to worry about swagger just code your api.

Comment: @HelderSepu: Maybe the OP is using the design-first approach, that is generating code from the spec and not vice versa.

Comment: Related: [Use object-type query param in OpenAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38187187/113116), [How to define parameters with square brackets in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48491688/113116)

Answer (score 4):

Your example is not an *array* of objects but two separate object parameters - `filter` and `order[]`, each serialized using the [`deepObject`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query) style (supported in OpenAPI 3.0). You can describe these parameters as follows:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.2
...

paths:
  /something:
    get:
      # ?filter[id]=1&filter[name]=bob&order[][name]=asc&order[][age]=desc
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: filter
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              id:
                type: integer
                example: 1
              name:
                type: string
                example: bob
          style: deepObject

        - in: query
          name: order[]
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
                example: asc
              age:
                type: string
                example: desc
          style: deepObject
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but the answer above is misleading

array of objects s is not supported in OpenAPI 3.0/3.1 Specifications currently defines

see the question [OpenAPI query string parameter with list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892768/openapi-query-string-parameter-with-list-of-objects)