# How to define parameters with square brackets in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an endpoint with query parameters that use square brackets:

```
GET /info?sort[name]=1&sort[age]=-1
```

Here, `name` and `age` are the field names from my model definition.

How can I write an OpenAPI (Swagger) definition for these parameters?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on which version of OpenAPI (Swagger) you use.

#### OpenAPI 3.x

The `sort` parameter can be defined an an object with the `name` and `age` properties. The parameter [serialization method](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/) should be `style: deepObject` and `explode: true`.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

paths:
  /info:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: sort
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: integer
                example: 1
              age:
                type: integer
                example: -1
          style: deepObject
          explode: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

This is supported in Swagger UI 3.15.0+ and Swagger-Editor 3.5.6+.

**Important:** The `deepObject` serialization style only supports simple non-nested objects with primitive properties, such as in the example above. The behavior for nested objects and arrays of objects [is not defined](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1706).

In other words, while we can define

```
?param[foo]=...&param[bar]=...
```

there's currently no way to define more nested query parameters such as

```
?param[0][foo]=...&param[1][bar]=...
or
?param[foo][0][smth]=...&?param[foo][1][smth]=
```

If you need the syntax for deeply nested query parameters, upvote and follow this feature request:
[Support deep objects for query parameters with deepObject style](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1706)

#### OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0)

`sort[name]` and `sort[age]` need to be defined as individual parameters:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...
paths:
  /info:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: sort[name]
          type: integer
        - in: query
          name: sort[age]
          type: integer
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```