# Are numeric indexes in the query parameter array representable in Swagger 2.0?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-2.0

I understand how to represent the array in query parameters with Swagger 2.0:

```
?list=x&list=y
```

Is it possible to represent an array in Swagger 2.0 using an indexed style?

```
?list[0]=x&list[1]=y
```

Comment: Related (but covers string indexes, rather than numeric indexes): [How to define parameters with square brackets in OpenAPI (Swagger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48491688/113116)

Answer (score 1):

#### OpenAPI 2.0 (fka Swagger 2.0)

`list[0]`, `list[1]`, `list[2]` ... `list[N]` must be defined as separate query parameters. There's no way to define `list` as a single array-type parameter and have it serialized the way you want.

Note that this approach only works for fixed-sized arrays whose maximum size is known in advance.

```yaml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: list[0]
    type: string
  - in: query
    name: list[1]
    type: string
```

#### OpenAPI 3.0

One approach is to define `list[0]`, `list[1]`, etc. as separate query parameters (like in the OpenAPI 2.0 example above). This approach is suitable for fixed-sized arrays whose maximum size is known in advance.

```yaml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: list[0]
    schema:
      type: string
  - in: query
    name: list[1]
    schema:
      type: string
```

Another approach - suitable for arrays of unknown size - is to define such an array using [free-form query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49582559/113116). The limitation of this approach is that it allows *arbitrary* parameter names - not just `list[n]` but also `abcde`. However, you can provide a `description` explaining that the parameter names must be in the format `list[n]`, and also provide an `example` value for documentation purposes.

```yaml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: params  # arbitrary name, not used in the actual query string
    description: >-
      Parameter names must be in the format `list[n]`
      where `n` is an integer starting from 0.
    schema:
      type: object
    example:
      list[0]: x
      list[1]: y
      list[2]: z
```

In Swagger UI, enter the query parameters in the JSON object (not array) format, like so:

```json
{
  "list[0]": "x",
  "list[1]": "y",
  "list[2]": "z"
}
```

Swagger UI will convert this into the following query string (before URL encoding):

```
?list[0]=x&list[1]=y&list[2]=z
```

#### OpenAPI 3.1

OAS 3.1 takes us one step forward. You would still use the [free-form query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49582559/113116) approach but narrow it down by using the new [`patternProperties`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#pattern-properties) keyword to specify a regular expression for the allowed parameter names (e.g. `^list\[\d+\]$`).

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

parameters:
  - in: query
    name: params  # arbitrary name, not used in the actual query string
    description: >-
      Parameter names must be in the format `list[n]`
      where `n` is an integer starting from 0.
    schema:
      type: object
      patternProperties:   # <--------
        ^list\[\d+\]$:
          type: string
      additionalProperties: false
    example:
      list[0]: x
      list[1]: y
      list[2]: z
```

Comment: how to implement separate query parameters without knowing the array size!?

Comment: @MohamedAdel I updated the answer. You'll need OAS 3.0 or 3.1 for that.