# Swagger is unable to make request with query string having json?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Have this schema

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: SampleApi
  description: Sample backend service
  version: 1.0.0
components:
  securitySchemes:
    apiKey:
      type: apiKey
      name: X-API-TOKEN
      in: header
  schemas: {}
paths:
  /api/v2/data/thing:
    get:
      tags:
        - Data
      parameters:
        - schema:
            type: string
          in: query
          name: searchText
          required: false
        - schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              page:
                type: number
                minimum: 0
              limit:
                type: number
                maximum: 100
            additionalProperties: false
          in: query
          name: pagination
          required: true
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Default Response
servers: []
```

The ui looks likes this. Notice when i executed the call, it didn't pass the "pagination" as parent key.

> /api/v2/data/thing?page=0&limit=100

[image]

But when i manually adds the pagination key it works.

> /api/v2/data/thing?pagination[page]=0&pagination[limit]=100

[image]

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [How to define parameters with square brackets in OpenAPI (Swagger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48491688/113116)

Answer (score 0):

To serialize your `pagination` object parameter in this format:

```
?pagination[page]=...&pagination[limit]=...
```

you need to add `style: deepObject` to the parameter definition:

```yaml
        - schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              page:
                type: number
                minimum: 0
              limit:
                type: number
                maximum: 100
            additionalProperties: false
          in: query
          name: pagination
          required: true
          style: deepObject # <----------
```

More info: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query