# OpenAPI query string parameter with list of objects

Tags: json, swagger, jsonschema, openapi

I am trying to document with [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/specification) a query string which look like

```
filtered[0][id]=code&filtered[0][value]=12345
```

and contains a list of object with properties `id` and `value`.

My `yaml` documentation looks like the following

```
parameters:
    - name: filtered
      in: query
      description: filters to be applied
      explode: true
      style: deepObject
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          properties:
            id:
              description: name of the field to be filtered
              type: string
            value:
              description: value of the filter
          type: object
```

The problem is the following: it looks like the `style: deepObject` option works only for one level, and not at the second level where my objects actually are. That is, it expects a query string like

```
?sorted[0]=%7B%0A%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%0A%20%20%22value%22%3A%20true%0A%7D
```

with the object not serialized as an array with `id` and `value` keys.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: can you provide encode version of query

Comment: deepobject is still not native jason just enumeration of all object properties or elements

Comment: @serge i would like to encode my query string as `filtered[0][id]=code&filtered[0][value]=12345`

Comment: Well by name deep object aplies to objects. Is it an option to put your list inside an object

Comment: no, it is not an option. The frontend is using a library (react-table) which uses that format. That is what I need to document, I can't change it

Answer (score 17):

**This is not possible as of OpenAPI 3.1**

OpenAPI 3.0/3.1 Specifications currently defines the `deepObject` behavior **only for simple objects** (with primitive properties) such as

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "Bob"
}
```

but [not for arrays](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1006#issuecomment-289196647) and [not for nested objects](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1706).

Since the behavior for arrays and nested objects is not defined, there's really no way to describe your query string. Technically, the only way would be to define `filtered[0][id]`, `filtered[0][value]`, etc. as individual query parameters.

If you are designing a new API (rather than describing an existing one), consider passing the array of objects in the request body instead.

Comment: Seems that the main use case for nested objects in the query parameters is filtering and searching, which implies GET. [Popular opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering) seems to indicate that using POST with search values in the request body [is a bad idea](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/233164/how-do-searches-fit-into-a-restful-interface).

Comment: @myol : Do u have another idea better than a POST ?

Comment: We used GET in the end and used `pattern` in the schema description for the parameter to match a regex. Its not great but it works for very basic nested objects

Answer (score 2):

As name implies, :), deepObject style only "provides a simple way of rendering *nested objects*", not arrays. At the least according to Version 3.0.1 it applies only to objects.

Note that even nested objects might be not yet supported by tools because the specification "does not provide such examples".

So your format is not compatible with Open API, yet may be you can define you query as parameters which follow a regex. I such cases usually I do my best yet provide some explanation

https://swagger.io/specification/

Update. Apparently, after somebody demanded a 'descriptive error' message for nested objects, a patch (PR) to support nested objects was suggested at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/pull/1450 . Regretfully it was decided not to incorporate this feature, and PR 1450 was rejected.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but starting open api 3 there is a support for what you looking for
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#schema-vs-content.

it was reported as a bug that was fixed with openapi generator 6.0.1 +
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4808

```
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: filter
    content:
      application/json:      
        schema:
          schema:
           $ref: "#/components/schemas/Filter"
```