# How to pass list of class object in get method - asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to pass list of class object in my ASP.Net Core 2.1 Controller. I am getting empty object with count 0. I have used attribute `[FromQuery], [FromRoute]` but the result remain same. My parameter class is as follows:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public int EpfNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get the list of Employee Class in my Controller like this:

```
[Route("[action]")]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> GetEmployeeByEmpCode([FromQuery]List<Employee> emp)
{
    //----------Doing my stuff.
    return Ok(1);
}
```

Here in the `emp` parameter I am getting empty list. By googling the issue, I got that I need to use `[FromUri]`. But the `[FromUri]` is used in Asp.Net WebApi 2, not asp.net core. If I simply add list of string as parameter then it works. The problem is with the class object as peremeter.

My question is how to pass list of class object as peremeter in Asp.Net Core 2.1 controller?

Comment: You can also utilize the following answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810278/net-core-web-api-accept-list-of-integers-as-an-input-param-in-http-get-api

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810278/net-core-web-api-accept-list-of-integers-as-an-input-param-in-http-get-api

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892768/openapi-query-string-parameter-with-list-of-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use FromBody to see if it work. I'm not sure what kind of technology you use (angular, react etc..) to submit the data to the controller

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> GetEmployeeByEmpCode([FromBody]List<Employee> emp)
{

    return Ok(1);
}
```

Comment: I am using Angular 7 as client side technology

Comment: Then you can use FromBody

Comment: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body. while using FromBody

Comment: Then your design is wrong. No one using get request to post List of object. Try to use POST. Check my answer again

Comment: There can be requirement of getting from the list of parameter.... Using POST I am able to do my job. But I am not actually posting my data rather I am trying get

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810278/net-core-web-api-accept-list-of-integers-as-an-input-param-in-http-get-api