# Model not displaying in swagger UI .NET

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

A model class `userQuery` that I have written isn't showing up in Swagger UI. I have referenced it in my controller file so I expected it to show up in the Swagger UI. I use SwashBuckle. What am I missing here?

The controller file having an endpoint:

```
using Project.Models;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Policy = "Read-Run")]
    [Route("byRoute/{element}")]        
    [Produces(typeof(EntityResult<EntityResponse>))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ListEntities([FromQuery] userQuery entityMatch, string element)
    {
        return Ok((await _entityService.ListEntities(entityMatch, element)));
    }

}
```

Model class:

```
using System;

namespace Project.Models
{
    public class UserQuery
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't bind complex objects to query string parameters in Swashbuckle (or OpenAPI): [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407054/how-to-pass-complex-object-as-a-query-string-in-swagger-using-swashbuckle).

You can use three different parameters: Id, DateCreated, and DateUpdated in your controller and use the [FromQuery] attribute for each of them.

Your endpoint will look like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ListEntities(
    [FromRoute] string element,
    [FromQuery] int id, 
    [FromQuery] DateTime? dateCreated,
    [FromQuery] DateTime? DateUpdated
)
```

Or you can pass the object in the body of the request and use the [FromBody] attribute. But usually, you shouldn't use the body for a GET request.