# Swagger/OpenAPI: What are valid ways to define arrays in query parameters?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have seen multiple ways to define arrays in query parameters in Swagger- and OpenAPI specifications. Are all the below examples valid? Are there more valid options?

Example 1:

```
...
{
    "name": "example",
    "in": "query",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
...
```

Example 2:

```
...
{
    "name": "example",
    "in": "query",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "properties": {
            "username": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "password": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Example 3:

```
...
{
    "name": "example",
    "in": "query",
    "type": "array",
    "schema": {
        "items": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
...
```

Example 4:

```
...
{
    "name": "example",
    "in": "query",
    "type": "array",
    "schema": {
        "items": {
            "properties": {
                "username": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "password": {
                    "type": "string",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Are there more options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples 1 and 3 are basically the same, and so are examples 2 and 4. The difference is the version of the OpenAPI Specification used: examples without `schema` are OpenAPI 2.0 syntax (`swagger: 2.0`); with `schema` - OpenAPI 3 syntax (`openapi: 3.x.x`). The `schema` keyword wraps type-related keywords in OpenAPI 3.0 parameter definitions.

Both OpenAPI 2.0 and 3 **only support arrays of primitives in query parameters.**

**Example 1** is a valid OpenAPI 2.0 parameter definition.

In OpenAPI 3, the same parameter would be defined with a `schema` containing the `type` and `items`:

```json
// openapi: 3.0.0

{
    "name": "example",
    "in": "query",
    "schema": {    // <--------------
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
}
```

**Example 2** - not valid. This is an OpenAPI 2.0 definition, and OAS 2 explicitly disallows arrays of objects in query parameters. It only supports arrays of primitives and arrays of arrays.

**Example 3** - almost, but not quite. This seems to be OpenAPI 3, in which case `type: array` must be inside the `schema`, like so:

```json
// openapi: 3.0.0

{
    "name": "example",
    "in": "query",
    "schema": {
      "type": "array",    // <--------------
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
}
```

**Example 4** - again, `type: array` must be inside the `schema` to make this definition *syntactically* correct. However, this example defines an array of objects, for which the [serialization behavior is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67745944/113116). So this example is actually **undefined behavior**.