# NestJs/Swagger(OpenAPI) defining nested objects in query parameters

Tags: swagger, nestjs, openapi

I'm trying to correctly define OpenAPI spec for the purposes of generating api client from that spec. I've encoutered a problem where we have a complex query object with nested objects and arrays of objects for get a GET route.

Lets take these classes as an example.

```
class Person {
  @ApiProperty()
  name!: string
  @ApiProperty()
  location!: string
}

class CompanyDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  name!: string

  @ApiProperty({
    type: [Person],
  })
  employees!: Person[]
}
```

And a get request with @Query decorator.

```
  @Get('test')
  async testing(@Query() dto: CompanyDto): Promise<void> {
    // ...
  }
```

What I'm getting is.

```
    {
      get: {
        operationId: 'testing',
        parameters: [
          {
            name: 'name',
            required: true,
            in: 'query',
            schema: {
              type: 'string',
            },
          },
          {
            name: 'name',
            in: 'query',
            required: true,
            schema: {
              type: 'string',
            },
          },
          {
            name: 'location',
            in: 'query',
            required: true,
            schema: {
              type: 'string',
            },
          },
        ],
        responses: {
          '200': {
            description: '',
          },
        },
        tags: ['booking'],
      },
    }
```

I've also tries to define Query params by adding @ApiQuery decorator and it almost works.

```
  @ApiQuery({
    style: 'deepObject',
    type: CompanyDto,
  })
```

--

```
{
  get: {
    operationId: 'testing',
    parameters: [
      {
        name: 'name',
        required: true,
        in: 'query',
        schema: {
          type: 'string',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'name',
        in: 'query',
        required: true,
        schema: {
          type: 'string',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'location',
        in: 'query',
        required: true,
        schema: {
          type: 'string',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'name',
        in: 'query',
        required: true,
        schema: {
          type: 'string',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'employees',
        in: 'query',
        required: true,
        schema: {
          type: 'array',
          items: {
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Person',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: '',
      },
    },
    tags: ['booking'],
  },
}
```

However now I'm getting duplicate query definitions mashed in to one. Is there a way to prevent or overwrite @Query definition? Or just a better way to define complex @Query in general?

Comment: OpenAPI [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67745944/113116) nested objects in query parameters. Send nested objects in the POST request body instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use POST for requests with nested objects. However I would still like to use GET for non-nested objects. Is there any way to overwrite or disable spec generation from @Query decorator to prevent duplicate parameter definition?

Comment: I'm not famliar with NestJs. Maybe someone else here knows.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating a custom decorator to extract query without generating OpenAPI Spec.

```
export const SilentQuery = createParamDecorator(
  (data: string | undefined, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest()
    if (data) {
      return request.query[data]
    } else {
      return request.query
    }
  },
)
```

So now you can use @ApiQuery with deepObject style.

Also if your're using ValidationPipes with class-validator for example. Make sure to set validateCustomDecorators to true

```
@SilentQuery(new ValidationPipe({ validateCustomDecorators: true }))
```

Answer (score 0):

I forked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71031428/17993530) it worked great but I was wondering how I could do it better. Now it works like a native query but only with support for nested objects

```js
import {
  createParamDecorator,
  ExecutionContext,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { DECORATORS} from "@nestjs/swagger/dist/constants"


export const CustomQuery = createParamDecorator(
  (data: string | undefined, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest()
    if (data) {
      return request.query[data]
    } else {
      return request.query
    }
  }, [
    (target, key: string, index) => {
      const queryParamsType = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target, key);

      Reflect.defineMetadata(
        DECORATORS.API_PARAMETERS,
        [
          {
            in: "query",
            type: queryParamsType[index],
            style: "deepObject",
            required: false,
            description: `query parameters ${key} controller`
          }
        ],
        target[key]
      );

      return target[key];
    }
  ]
)
```

how do use it:

```js
  @ApiOperation({ summary: "Получить все карты" })
  @Get('/')
  async getAll(@CustomQuery() query: QueryCardsDto): Promise<PageDto<CardModel> | CardModel[]> {
    return this.cardService.getAllCards(query)
  }
```

for work ValidationPipes for CustomQuery im did next in file main.ts:

```js
 app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      validateCustomDecorators: true, // <---- added this
      transform: true,
      whitelist: true,
      exceptionFactory(errors: ValidationError[]) {
        return new UnprocessableEntityException(
          errors,
          "The given data was invalid."
        );
      }
    })
  );
```