# using a two dimensional array in swagger php api

Tags: php, api, openapi, swagger-editor, swagger-php

i want to get a get request http://localhost/api/catalog/product/list?filters[filter14][]=0
but in swagger it turns out only [image]

[image]

how to create two dimensional array input in swagger editor?

Answer (score 1):

OpenAPI 3.x [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67780788/113116) nested arrays and nested objects in query strings. You'll need to either pass those filters in the request body (e.g. as a JSON object or array), or replace the `filters` parameter with individual named filter parameters.