# Swagger 3.0 open ApI yaml Multivaluemap

Tags: rest, spring-boot, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am designing an API with YAML first approach using openapi 3.0. There is a requirement to define Search API which will be A GET request and will take more than 10 values as search params.

I am using swagger codegen to generate spring boot server stubs from this YAMLs. How to define the YAMl , so that the codegen generates Multivaluemap as request parameter. Rather than having 10 different search parameters, because sonar lint will show that as a bad code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use object type query param in OpenAPI documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38187187/113116), [How to document dynamic query parameter names in OpenAPI (Swagger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49582559/113116)

Comment: Thanks Helen. But Swagger codegen does not handle it properly. It creates a Map<string,string>. Now when I pass multiple query parameters , i get an obvious error that no proper converter for string to map. I want swagger codegen to creeate a spring Multivaluemap with no request param name, like we do in the spring implementations i.e.  pulic ResponseEntity getVal(@RequestParam Multivaluemap<string,string> params){} like this.