# How to define free form object in parameters for OpenAPI3.0

Tags: python, swagger, openapi, connexion

I am trying to write config for OpenAPI with intention to resolve request like this:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/statistics?stratifications=color,blue,bodytype,normal
or
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/statistics?stratifications=color,blue,bodytype,normal,height,170
or just
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/statistics?stratifications=color,grey

into object that will get passed to my function. This is what I am writing in the config:

```
    get:
      tags: [statistics]
      operationId: api.v1.statistics.endpoints.get_statistics
      {% if not disable_security %}
      security:
        - jwt: [statistics]
        {% endif %}

      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: stratifications
          description: Stratifications of statistic
          schema:
            type: object
          style: form
          explode: false
```

but this results in

`is not of type 'object'`

error in jsonschema since jsonschema expect dictionary and getting string `color,blue,bodytype,normal,height,170` instead. Are there way to add encoder there? I though style define encoder but it seems to be not the case.

Comment: Your parameter definition is correct. This seems to be an issue with the server-side framework that deserializes the parameter from the query string.

Comment: I am using connexion==2.5.1

Comment: Open an issue with connexion then

Comment: Have you tried define your object properties (in your case stratifications) and use explode: true ? Maybe this question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187187/use-object-type-query-param-in-swagger-documentation/38188832#51277233