# How to declare query object in the parameters?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I'm trying to define a query object in OpenAPI 3:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - name: query
          in: query
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              id:
                type: number
            required:
              - id
```

But the example value and schema is not shown in Swagger UI.

[image]

Is there a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Related: [Use object type query param in Swagger documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38187187/113116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is correct.

> but example value and schema was not shown in swaager ui.

The example **is** actually shown, in the JSON key/value format:

```json
{
  "id": 0
}
```

"Try it out" will serialize this parameter according to the defined [serialization method](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/), in this case as the `?id=<value>` query string.

The issue with the schema not being displayed for query parameters of `type: object` is a known limitation, it's tracked here:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4581