# How to wrap up query parametrs into a custom model in swagger

Tags: java, rest, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

Similar Problem :
[Use object type query param in swagger documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187187/use-object-type-query-param-in-swagger-documentation)

**My ask :**

I have an API for which lets I have 3 query parameters but in the future, it can have multiple parameters with different datatypes. So instead of directly mentioning them in my `api-doc.yaml` I want to create a model(class) which can hold all these parameters. Please note I only want to go with this solution. I know we can pass it in the body. But I am in a tightly coupled setup hence I am interested to see how we can wrap these parameters into a single class

**My current implementation:**
My `api-defs.yaml` file where I am defining this model as a schema `PayloadQueryParams`

```
PayloadQueryParams:
  type: object
  properties:
    workflow:
      type: string
      required: true
    timestamp:
      type: integer
      format: int64
      required : true
    createdTill:
      type: integer
      format: int64
      description: "timestamp in ms for querying scheduler service tasks"
      required : false
    page:
      type: integer
      description: "page number for scheduled tasks"
      required: false
```

Now I am trying to use this model, into my `api-internal.yaml`

```
  /tasks:
    get:
      tags:
        - "internal"
      operationId: "getTask"
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name : PayloadQueryParams
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PayloadQueryParams'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/ResponseModel'
        "401":
          description: "Unauthorized"
          content: { }
        "403":
          description: "Forbidden"
          content: { }
```

Now usually my approach stays is that with this codegen structure generates a custom boiler plater interface which I implement into my controller layer and override methods,

**PROBLEM**
With above structure problem I am facing is

1. The methods codegen is generating (`getTask`) that is created with model `PayloadQueryParams` which I expect it to do but the problem is when I am trying to send query parameters from the URLs its receiving it as null.
2. As part of testing I removed all these definitions from swagger and created my own query paramter class `PayloadQueryParams` exactly same which was generated by swagger and when I try to use that directly into my controller layer, my UTs are working fine that means when I send the query params from URL they are parsed correctly
3. But as I mentioned I cant go with the setup-2 I have to do same thing via swagger codegen
4. I have validated by copying the exact definition of class `PayloadQueryParams` generated by swagger into my own custom class, even when they are identical, my APIs without swagger are working but not working when I used swagger codegen for generating query param model

**SOLUTIONS I EXPECT**

1. Is there any structual problem in my yaml files ?
2. I am on openAPI so I belive that is not the problem
3. Is there any other way we can get these query parameters into a hashmap or multivalue map

Comment: _"when I am trying to send query parameters from the URLs its receiving it as null."_ - this could be an issue with the specific server/client codegen that you used, or with the code you use to send the request. It's hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: @Helen I doubt this could be the issue because I am using some UTs for the testing ,so to validate this first I ran the model generated by swagger and then I ran the model which I wrote manually the one which was created by me was successfull on TCs. I mean from my finding I believe there is either some problem in my yaml syntax or I am doubtful that can we pass the schema in the way I am using it for the query parameters

Comment: Your OpenAPI definition (and the usage of an object schema as a query parameter) is correct and means that the URL query string is formatted as `/tasks?workflow=...&timestamp=...&createdTill=...&page=...`. There's just one small error in the definition: the required object properties must be specified in the `required: [prop1, prop2, ...]` list on the object level ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40113571/113116)); properties themselves don't have the `required: true/false` attribute.

Comment: Since the `PayloadQueryParams` schema lives in a separate file, you probably need to change the parameter schema `$ref` to: `$ref: 'path/to/api-defs.yaml#/PayloadQueryParams` or similar.

Comment: ok thanks @Helen, thanks for the input but on applying those above too I am not able to resolute it. Please do let me know if you have any reference examples where we are creating a custom model for query params or some reference for this, I spent a much time on this so I am going without any model for now